# I tried creating a table and it did not work as expected

Tags: tables

Good people, can anyone help me?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}       % Default font size and paper size
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                 % Permite usar os caracteres acentuadas etc
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}              % Configurar a linguagem do documento
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                    % Permite hifenização correta dos caracteres ex:doc-umento
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{fontspec}                        % Carregar Fonts
\usepackage{graphicx}                       % Pacote de Imagens
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tikz}                           % Pacote gráfico
\usepackage{color}                          % Pacote de cores do Latex
\usepackage{xcolor}                         % Pacote com mais variaçoes de cores do Latex
\usepackage{tabularx}                       % Pacote para Tabelas
\usepackage{hyperref}                       % Pacote para hipertexto, links para referências e figuras
    \hypersetup{colorlinks,breaklinks,urlcolor=letter_color, linkcolor=letter_color}
\usepackage{fontawesome}                    % Pacote de Simbolos
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
\usepackage[big]{layaureo}                 %better formatting of the A4 page    
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                Configuration for fonts
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{titlesec}                       % custom \section
\titleformat{\section}{\bfseries\Large\scshape\raggedright}{}{0em}{}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{3pt}{3pt}
\hyphenation{im-pre-se}
\textblockorigin{2mm}{0.8\paperheight}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   EDUCATION
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{tabular}{p{9cm} p{9cm}}
{\color{letter_color}\section{Educação}}
    \textsc{Set 2009 - Presente}\\
    Mestrado Integrado em Engenharia Eletrotécnica e de Computadores
    \textbf{Áreas de estudo}: Controlo,Energias e Sistemas Digitais
     &    
    {\color{letter_color}\section{Educação}}
    \textsc{Set 2009 - Presente}
    Mestrado Integrado em Engenharia Eletrotécnica e de Computadores
    \textbf{Áreas de estudo}: Controlo,Energias e Sistemas Digitais
\end{tabular}
```

[image]

Comment: So what's your problem here? I assume it's the vertical mis-alignment of the `\section`s you placed inside a `tabular`, correct?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Please also provide a full MWE with `\documentclass`, necessary libraries and `\begin{document}…\end{document}`.

Comment: The output looks like the columns are `m{..}p{..}` is that really generated from the code you showed with `p{..}p{..}` ?

Comment: Please write in English!

Answer (score 3):

Use `\newline` or `\par` instead of `\\`.

```
\begin{tabular}{p{7cm}p{7cm}}
    \section{\color{green!40!blue}Educação}
    \textsc{Set 2009 - Presente}\par
    Mestrado Integrado em Engenharia Eletrotécnica e de Computadores
    \textbf{Áreas de estudo}: Controlo,Energias e Sistemas Digitais
     &    
    \section{\color{green!40!blue}Educação}
    \textsc{Set 2009 - Presente}\par
    Mestrado Integrado em Engenharia Eletrotécnica e de Computadores
    \textbf{Áreas de estudo}: Controlo,Energias e Sistemas Digitais
\end{tabular}
```

> [image]